# Inserting data from jquery mobile page to a database

Tags: jquery, database, asp-classic

please i'm an asp.vb developer and new to jquery mobile. i have a page that i want to insert data from it to an ms access database using jquery mobile. please can only one be of help? here is my html:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="sources/quest_rev.asp">
          <table width="525" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3">
            <tr>
              <td width="59"><strong>Reply</strong></td>
              <td width="445"><textarea name="reply" cols="60" id="reply"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><strong>Name</strong></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="uname" id="uname" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><strong>Number</strong></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="unumber" id="unumber" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><strong>Location</strong></td>
              <td><label for="location"></label>
              <input type="text" name="location" id="location" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td><input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="  Send  " /></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

When the form is submitted, you need to send an ajax request to the server, then the server should save the form data to the ms access database.

jQuery cannot insert any data to the database

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('#form1').submit(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: '<url>',
            type: 'POST',
            data: $(this).serialize()
        }).done(function(data){
            //do something
        });
        return false;
    })
})
```

Comment: please how do i make the call?

Comment: please i guess the '<url>' should have the url of my insertion script right? example '<../path/insert_script.asp>'.

Comment: @user2522201 yes, it is the asp page which will receive the form params and insert it it the db

Comment: please i've tried inserting the script on the page just now and realize when you submit the page doesn't post at all. the page remains static and nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

This may help you to do what you want : http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Send-and-Receive-JSON-objects-to-Web-Service-Methods-using-jQuery-AJAX-in-ASPNet.aspx